# Maximum call stack size exceeded error during recursive calls

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I've been trying to solve a recursion question `islandPerimeter`

```js
/**
 * @param {number[][]} grid
 * @return {number}
 */
var islandPerimeter = function (grid) {
  let visitedLand = new Set();

  function dfs(i, j) {
    if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > grid.length || j > grid[0].length || grid[i][j] == 0) return 0;
    if (visitedLand.has({ i: j })) return 1;

    visitedLand.add({ i: j });

    let perimeter = dfs(i, j + 1);
    perimeter += dfs(i + 1, j);
    perimeter += dfs(i, j - 1);
    perimeter += dfs(i - 1, j);

    return perimeter;
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
      if (grid[i][j]) {
        return dfs(i, j);
      }
    }
  }
};

let nums = [
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0],
  [1, 1, 0, 0],
];
islandPerimeter(nums);
```

I've initialised this function of `dfs()`inside my main function but it shows this...

```
function dfs(i, j) {
              ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

```
if (i < 0 || j < 0 || i > grid.length || j > grid[0].length || grid[i][j] == 0)
                                                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '1')
```

There's two `for()` loops that first calls this `dfs` function and inside it I'm again calling them.
Please explain what's this issue, I've read a few threads that this is regarding over calling the recursion. Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

When the expression `{i: j}` occurs twice in your code, they are two distinct objects. Therefore, the `Set` does not recognize the second object as the same as the first:

```
> visitedLand.has({1: 2})
false
> visitedLand.add({1: 2})
Set(1) { { '1': 2 } }
> visitedLand.has({1: 2})
false
```

As a consequence, the `return 1;` statement is never reached, and the recursion goes on ad infinitum.

Use strings `i + "-" + j` rather than objects.

Also, replace

```
i > grid.length || j > grid[0].length
```

with

```
i >= grid.length || j >= grid[0].length
```

because `grid[grid.length]` is already undefined.

Comment: Yes, this indeed worked, but it's showing TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined. I've added it in the last of question